# Create Rows to Column in (RAPID) SQL without PIVOT

Tags: sql, rapidsql

I am using the query below to pull up a list of accounts and the optional codes that go with them.  There are 95 codes for each account, not just the 2 I am showing in the results below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Ref1.ACCOUNT_ID as Acct_Numb,
Current_Date as DATA_DATE,
Cat.OPTIONAL_CTGRY_CD As Code,
Cat.OPTIONAL_CTGRY_CD || ' - ' || Cat.OPTIONAL_CTGRY_NM AS Code_Combo,
Class.OPTIONAL_CLASS_CD as Code_Answer,
Class.OPTIONAL_CLASS_NM as Code_Answer_Desc

FROM xxxxx.zzzzzz_OPT_REF Ref1

LEFT JOIN xxxxx.zzzzzz_OPT_CATEGORY Cat
ON xxxxx.zzzzzz_OPT_REF.OPTIONAL_CTGRY_CD = xxxxx.zzzzzz_OPT_CATEGORY.OPTIONAL_CTGRY_CD

LEFT JOIN xxxxx.zzzzzz_OPT_CLASS Class
ON xxxxx.zzzzzz_OPT_REF.OPTIONAL_CLASS_CD = xxxxx.zzzzzz_OPT_CLASS.OPTIONAL_CLASS_CD
AND xxxxx.zzzzzz_OPT_CATEGORY.OPTIONAL_CTGRY_CD = xxxxx.zzzzzz_OPT_CLASS.OPTIONAL_CTGRY_CD

LEFT JOIN xxxxx.HRTVACT_PCS Acct
ON xxxxx.ACCOUNT_ID = Acct.ACCOUNTID

WHERE xxxxx.ACCOUNTSTATUS = 'OPEN' AND xxxxx.ACCOUNTID = '123456' OR xxxxx.ACCOUNTID = '654321'

ORDER BY ACCT_NUMB ASC, CODE ASC;
```

Here are the results

```
DATA_DATE   ACCT_NUMB   CODE   CODE_COMBO      CODE_ANSWER  CODE_ANSWER_DESC
11/8/2016     123456     1    1 - Reporting        0     NOT APPLICABLE
11/8/2016     123456     2    2 - System           4     SYSTEM 2
11/8/2016     654321     1    1 - Reporting        3     APPLIED
11/8/2016     654321     2    2 - System           3     N/A
```

I need to create the results as a pivot table that looks like the table below.

```
                       (CODE)  (CODE_COMBO)    (CODE)    (CODE_COMBO)   
DATA_DATE   ACCT_NUMB     1    1 - Reporting     2        2 - System
11/8/2016    123456       0    NOT APPLICABLE    4         SYSTEM 2    (CODE_ANSWER)/(CODE_ANSWER_DESC)
11/8/2016    654321       3    APPLIED           3         N/A         (CODE_ANSWER)/(CODE_ANSWER_DESC)
```

I have not tried this before and I am stumped

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this in the past using table alias so that you can join a table to itself.  I have done it with 4 or 5 columns not 95 so there may be a better way that I am not aware of.